# Hide Object Based on Cell Value

Tags: excel, vba, shapes

I have an object (i.e. a rectangle called "Shape") in a spreadsheet that I would like to hide based on a cell value (A1). Here's what I've tried after doing a search on the internet but it doesn't work. I apologize, I'm not a VBA expert by any means. I'm usually able to muddle through based on web searches but this one is stumping me.

```
Private Sub HideShape(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Row = 1 And Target.Column = 1 Then _
        Me.Shapes("Shape").Visible = (Cells(1, 1).Value = 1)
End Sub
```

I actually have six objects I want to handle similarly based on six cell values. Here's the code I tried:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Me.Shapes("ProjMgmt").Visible = (Me.Cells(101, 3).Value = 0)
    Me.Shapes("Planning").Visible = (Me.Cells(102, 3).Value = 0)
    Me.Shapes("Implementation").Visible = (Me.Cells(103, 3).Value = 0)
    Me.Shapes("Supplier").Visible = (Me.Cells(104, 3).Value = 0)
    Me.Shapes("Process").Visible = (Me.Cells(105, 3).Value = 0)
    Me.Shapes("Customer").Visible = (Me.Cells(106, 3).Value = 0)
End Sub
```

It works with one shape but doesn't run with these six shapes.

Comment: Were you trying to use the `Worksheet_Change` event? If so, you can't change `Worksheet_Change` to `HideShape`.

Comment: Thank you for that input. Is there a Macro I could use to get the same result perhaps?

Comment: Change `HideShape` back to `Worksheet_Change`.

Comment: Wow! That worked! Thank you so much BigBen!

Comment: How do I officially thank you on this board?

Comment: I will add this as an answer - you can then click the check mark to accept it.

Comment: One last twist. Is there a change in the code required if A1 were a calculated field? The code works if I enter 0 or 1 in A1 but if the value of A1 is calculated, the code no longer works.

Comment: You have to use `Worksheet_Calculate` for that, instead of `Worksheet_Change`.

Comment: What are your formulas in `C101:C106`?

Comment: The formulas calculate sums from another sheet. They are as follows:
C101 =SUM('Audit Questions'!I7:L13)
C102 =SUM('Audit Questions'!I16:L20)
C103 =SUM('Audit Questions'!I23:L30)
C104 =SUM('Audit Questions'!I33:L39)
C105 =SUM('Audit Questions'!I43:L47,'Audit Questions'!I50:L54,'Audit Questions'!I57:L59,'Audit Questions'!I62:L66,'Audit Questions'!I69:L72,'Audit Questions'!I75:L78)
C106 =SUM('Audit Questions'!I81:L85)

Comment: Are you sure they equal zero exactly and there's not a small decimal due to floating point error?

Comment: They would equal zero. They're reading from a table of binary values (i.e. if the cell equals this than 1, otherwise 0)

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior... You could `Debug.Print Me.Cells(101, 3).Value` and so on to perhaps see what their value actually is.

Comment: I saved the worksheet, shut down Excel, shut down my computer, rebooted and the whole thing started working for some reason. I can't thank you enough BigBen!

Comment: Hmm... interesting. Maybe calculation was manual?

Comment: Nope, all formulas auto-calculate.. It's certainly working as intended now though. Very slick! Thanks again!

Comment: Ahh - perhaps events were not enabled... In any case, feel free to click the check mark next to the answer to accept it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use the `Worksheet_Change` event, you can't change the `Worksheet_Change` to `HideShape`... it needs to be `Worksheet_Change`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Row = 1 And Target.Column = 1 Then _
        Me.Shapes("Shape").Visible = (Me.Cells(1, 1).Value = 1)
End Sub
```

If there is a formula in `A1`, then you have to use `Worksheet_Calculate`:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Me.Shapes("Shape").Visible = (Me.Cells(1, 1).Value = 1)
End Sub
```

Comment: How would I adjust the code to do the same for multiple shapes and cell values? I have six shapes that I would like to become visible or invisible based on six calculated cell values.

Comment: Copy the `Me.Shapes("Shape").Visible = (Me.Cells(1, 1).Value = 1)` line and change the `Cells` parameters and the expected value.

Comment: Hi BigBen. I tried that but it doesn't seem to work:

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Me.Shapes("ProjMgmt").Visible = (Me.Cells(101, 3).Value = 0)
    Me.Shapes("Planning").Visible = (Me.Cells(102, 3).Value = 0)
    Me.Shapes("Implementation").Visible = (Me.Cells(103, 3).Value = 0)
    Me.Shapes("Supplier").Visible = (Me.Cells(104, 3).Value = 0)
    Me.Shapes("Process").Visible = (Me.Cells(105, 3).Value = 0)
    Me.Shapes("Customer").Visible = (Me.Cells(106, 3).Value = 0)
End Sub

Comment: Maybe edit your question with what you've tried and the errors you're getting, if any.